# Trying to set up a windows share

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I am trying to share a folder, I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------
Open Folder
---------------------------
\\server\share is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.



Not enough server storage is available to process this command.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\IRPStackSize` to 50 (decimal).  It was originally 15 (decimal).

Comment: +1 Any idea what that setting actually does?

Comment: According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285089, it has something to do with how many stack frames (?) an I/O request can use, or something like that.

Comment: Some notes: * Setting the value to 16 may be enough (instead of 50). Or maybe not. * This has to be changed on the server machine, not the client. * You need to reboot after changing it, or at least go into services.msc and restart the Server service

Answer (score 0):

it happens when a firewall is blocking you, or when you trying to access windows with a blank password credentials.

you have to create a password for the remote account, and set the permission properties of the  \machinename\data to allow (all).

Comment: The firewall is completely off, and when I look up "Effective permissions" for my account on the share, I have "Full control".